# SESSION empty when using PHP.net alternative for session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, session

On php.net's manual page for session_regenerate_id they advise against using the function since you may run into problems if someone does not have a reliable internet connection. I used the code they propose as an alternative but run into problems.

```
function regenerateId(): bool {
    // code protecting against logouts due to unstable internet connections 
    // copied from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

    // New session ID is required to set proper session ID
    // when session ID is not set due to unstable network.
    $new_session_id = session_create_id();
    $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
    // Set destroy timestamp
    $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
        
    // Write and close current session;
    session_commit() ;

    // Start session with new session ID
    ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
    session_id($new_session_id);
    $result = session_start();
    //ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1); // gives error, elsewhere on php.net they removed this from the example
    die('<pre>'.$result.'/'.$new_session_id.'<br>'.print_r($_SESSION,true));
            
    // New session does not need them
    unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
    unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
    // die('regenerated: '. $_SESSION['UID']);
    return $result ;
}
```

I added the `die()` statement just to confirm why I was always logged out on regenerating the id: the $_SESSION array is empty.

Strange, since the code came directly from php.net (with one error removed, see comment). I am stuck and returned to the original `session_regenerate_id()`. I am on PHP 8.1.26

BTW The `session_commit()` and `session_start()` both return true.

Does anyone understand why the php.net code does not work and makes the `$_SESSION` completely empty? And/or how to fix it?

PS. I excluded the code that handles the `$_SESSION['destroyed']` since it's irrelevant to this problem. It's on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: Turns out there was someone else with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133504/properly-regenerating-session-ids . Hadn't found it before.

Comment: Leaving this question because of other wording, was hard to find the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it on StackOverflow: the code on php.net is not complete. Found it on [Properly regenerating session ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133504/properly-regenerating-session-ids):

```
keepSession = $_SESSION ;

// Write and close current session;
session_commit();

// Start session with new session ID
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
session_id($new_session_id);
$result = session_start();
$_SESSION = $keepSession
```

Keeping this question here because I couldn't find the other question at first, I think my wording might help other people looking for the same.